# Handling headers using utl_file upload procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, utl-file

I am trying to upload a csv file having headers into a table using UTL_FILE, but I am facing an issue. With normal upload using utl_file, the headers are also included and the data results to be recorded in double quotes(which I don't require). If I exclude headers by using an `if` condition as in below code and declaring headline variable, it uploads the records without headers but still in double quotes. When I manually remove headers from csv file it uploads fine without quotes. But the csv is created newly every day so headers can't be removed from file.

Please suggest some solution which matches the headers between target table and csv then uploads the csv file data. Below is my procedure.

```
create or replace procedure load_file_new(p_FileDir in varchar2, p_FileName in varchar2)
as
    v_FileHandle utl_file.file_type;
    v_NewLine varchar2(2000);
    v_a varchar2(100);
    v_b varchar2(100);
    v_c varchar2(100);
    v_d varchar2(100);

    p_ignore_headerlines number;

begin
    v_FileHandle := utl_file.fopen(p_FileDir, p_FileName, 'r', 32767);

    p_ignore_headerlines := 1;

    if p_ignore_headerlines > 0
    then
        begin
            for i in 1 .. p_ignore_headerlines
            loop
                utl_file.get_line(v_FileHandle, v_NewLine);
            end loop;
        end;
    end if;

    loop
        begin
            utl_file.get_line(v_FileHandle, v_NewLine);
        exception
            when no_data_found then
                exit;
        end;

        v_a := regexp_substr(v_NewLine, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, 1);
        v_b := regexp_substr(v_NewLine, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, 2);
        v_c := regexp_substr(v_NewLine, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, 3);
        v_d := regexp_substr(v_NewLine, '("[^"]*"|[^,]+)', 1, 4);

        merge into test using dual on (a = v_a)
            when not matched then insert (a, b, c, d)
                 values (v_a, v_b, v_c, v_d)
            when matched then update set
                 b = v_b, c = v_c, d = v_d where a = v_a;

    end loop;

    utl_file.fclose(v_FileHandle);
    commit;
end load_file_new;
```

Comment: Since you ultimately want to perform insert or update, `sqlloader` is a better tool and has much better options for such operations.

Comment: Hi Kaushik. I felt the same. Somehow i am restricted to use this on particular. Thanks

Comment: I am not clear what the doublequotes have got to do with the headers. Can't you just skip *n* records regardless of whether anything is in quotes or not?

Comment: To skip *n* lines, I would just have an `if` condition within the main file processing loop, rather than writing a whole separate loop just for skipping lines. (Also I would name all of my local variables with the same prefix, and keep `p_` for parameters.) However I can't see anything obviously wrong with the skipping logic other than it being a bit complicated.

Comment: @Ashish, can't you use that file as an **external table**? If so, you'd see it as if it was an "ordinary" table and, hopefully, perform *simple* SELECT statement(s) in order to load data into the target table.

Comment: Hi William. Thanks for the response. I thought of that too. What headers had to do with double quotes. Although the skipping part works, it skips the first line and upload well with that if condition but when viewed data it is all in double quotes like  "abc", "456". I practiced it manually by deleting the first line from csv file and there it uploads well and fine. What could be the reason for double quotes is what troubling me. Although quotes goes off if i remove headers line from the file but i need to have some automated solution.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, I thought of it as well and the sql loader for solution but i am tied to use utl_file. Need to figure out why double quotes are coming up. Can Regexp be the cause?

Comment: If you have double quotes but don't want them, a simple REPLACE would fix that.

Comment: @Littlefoot. Double quotes are not there in actual data. When uploaded they are coming by itself. Using Replace over regexp ?

Comment: Load first. Update (with REPLACE) next. That requires two phases, of course, but - if nothing else helps ...